# How to choose the family in Generalized Linear Model in R

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I would like to know how to choose the family in generalized linear models in R. Roughly, I have learned that `family=binomial` or `family=poisson` should be used if dependent variable (y) is binary or count data. How about others [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html)?

Especially,
in which situation of dependent variable(y), can I apply `family=Gamma` or `family=inverse.gaussian`?

Answer (score 3):

A good guide is to look at the relationship between the mean and the variance. If the variance does not vary with the mean - Gaussian. If it varies proportional to the mean - Poisson. As mean squared - gamma. As mean cubed - inverse Gaussian.

Comment: I don't fully subscribe to your last sentence. The variance of a gamma distribution is not really proportional to the square of the mean, even if it looks so when you look at the formula: the variance is the square of the mean *divided by the shape parameter* which can vary as well in a GLM, so the two are free to vary independently of each other.

Comment: I've submitted a [new question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522691) regarding this point, we'll see.